# duplicated values in a string - on submit

Tags: string, coldfusion, onsubmit, duplication

I have a hidden variable within a cfform. The value is an alphanumeric string, 4 characters long, like `Y876`. The value appears to be correctly set on the form page. On the submit page however, the string becomes a two item list, like: `Y876,Y876`.

I've checked this right at the top of the submit page. I've been doing casual CF dev at work for years and haven't seen this before (mostly forms, data storage and retrieval). What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 2):

You must have two input fields with the same name on the page.